# MYSQL Help - 2 Databases, 1 Featured Image

Tags: mysql, select, case

I currently have 2 MYSQL databases.

DatabaseOne is the full database with all cars, and the DatabaseTwo is focused on specific details of the car manufacturer. For example:

DatabaseOne has the car Manufacturer, model, year, color, and a **link to the picture of the car**.

DatabaseTwo has the Manufacturer, details on the manufacturer, the phone number, website, etc, along with a **featured_image_id**, which I can set to highlight a specific car from DatabaseOne, joining on matching ID.

Table data DatabaseOne:

```
    ID   |   Manufacturer   |   Model   |   Year   |   Color   |   ImageLink
    1    |   Toyota         |   Camry   |   2002   |   Black   |   88.jpg
    2    |   Toyota         |   Venza   |   2010   |   Black   |   91.jpg
    3    |   Mazda          |   Miata   |   2001   |   Red     |   77.jpg
    4    |   Mercedes       |   Benz    |   2012   |   Green   |   46.jpg
    5    |   Mercedes       |   Benz    |   2000   |   Blue    |   12.jpg
```

Table data DatabaseTwo:

```
    ID   |   Manufacturer   |   PhNumber   |   Website   |   FeaturedImage
    1    |   Toyota         |   555-5555   |   .com      |        2
    2    |   Mazda          |   555-5555   |   .com      |        3
    3    |   Mercedes       |   555-5555   |   .com      |
```

The databases join when the FeaturedImage from DatabaseTwo matches the ID of DatabaseOne.

In this case, Toyota would show the ImageLink (.jpg) for DatabaseOne ID 2 (Venza), Mazda would show the image of Mazda with DatabaseOne ID 3, and since the Mercedes FeaturedImage is not set, I want it to show the most recent Mercedes, which would be DatabaseOne ID 5.

What I am trying to do is display the results, categorized by the Manufacturers in DatabaseTwo, and if a featured_image_ID is set in DatabaseTwo, I want to show image_link from the matching ID in DatabaseOne, and if featured_image_id is not set, I just want to show the image_link of the most recent car by that manufacturer.

When displaying the results, when the second **CASE** in the below statement is preceded by "OR", all **recent** images of the cars show, *however* the Manufacturers with featured_image_id set will just show the recent associated image_link as well.

When the second **CASE** is preceded by "AND", **ONLY** the Manufacturer with the featured_image_id set will show up, and none of the other Manufacturers without featured_image_id show up.

I am trying to make sure all manufacturers show up with images, whether it is specifically set in DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id, or if not set, then falling back to the most recent image id by the matching manufacturer.

Here is my current MYSQL code:

```
    SELECT DatabaseOne.id, DatabaseOne.manufacturer, 
    DatabaseOne.model,DatabaseOne.year, DatabaseOne.picture, 
    DatabaseOne.image_link, DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id, 
    DatabaseTwo.title, DatabaseTwo.id, 
    IF(DatabaseTwo.id != 0, DatabaseTwo.id, 'N/A') AS card_id 
    FROM DatabaseOne 
    LEFT JOIN DatabaseTwo
    ON (CASE 
    WHEN (DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id != 0 AND DatabaseTwo.category = 'Manufacturer' 
    AND DatabaseTwo.Manufacturer = DatabaseOne.Manufacturer) 
    THEN (DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id = DatabaseOne.id) 
    END ) 
    WHERE DatabaseOne.Manufacturer != ''  
    AND DatabaseOne.id != 0 
    OR ((CASE 
    WHEN (DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id IS NOT NULL) 
    THEN (DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id != 0 ) END) ) 
    GROUP BY DatabaseOne.Manufacturer
    ORDER BY DatabaseOne.Manufacturer ASC, DatabaseOne.id DESC
```

Comment: `"if featured_image_id is not set, I just want to show the image_link of the most recent car by that manufacturer."` ... can you clarify by way of example what you mean by this?

Comment: For example, DatabaseTwo.featured_image_id field for Toyota will be set to "2", Joining it with DatabaseOne.ID 2, which in HTML will load that image_link from a Toyota DatabaseOne. If the featured_image_id is not set in DatabaseTwo for Toyota, then I want to show the DatabaseOne image_link from the most recently uploaded Toyota, whichever that may be.

Comment: Does `DatabaseOne` have a timestamp column which would allow us to determine which record has the most recent image upload for a model?

Comment: If I change the second CASE statement to say "OR ((CASE..." it will show all manufacturers and recent images, but ignores the featured_image_id. If I change the second CASE to say "...AND ((CASE..." it will only show the one manufacturer with the featured_image_id set, and none of the manufacturers which do not have a featured_image_id set in DatabaseTwo.

Comment: No it does not have timestamp, it is determining the most recently uploaded by ID. The highest DatabaseOne.id is the most recently uploaded, which is why I have it ordered DESC.

Comment: My advice: Show us actual table data.  I feel that you what you want to do is fairly straightforward, but the question is a bit unclear right now.

Comment: Updated with MYSQL table. As a side note, eventually there may also be a DatabaseThree for users, which will also have a FeaturedImage field, letting users set their pictures to those of the cars uploaded for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Manufacturer, t1.Model, t1.Year, t1.Color,
    t3.ImageLink
FROM DatabaseOne t1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT db2.Manufacturer,
        COALESCE(db2.FeaturedImage, t.DefaultFeaturedImage) AS FeaturedImage
    FROM DatabaseTwo db2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(ID) AS DefaultFeaturedImage, Manufacturer
        FROM DatabaseOne
        GROUP BY Manufacturer
    ) t
        ON db2.Manufacturer = t.Manufacturer
) t2
    ON t1.Manufacturer = t2.Manufacturer
INNER JOIN DatabaseOne t3
    ON t2.FeaturedImage = t3.ID
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4fbe8/6)

Comment: Thank you for your response - This seems very close -- I have integrated it with my code, and what it seems to be doing right now, is it is only loading the one Manufacturer where I set a Featured Image, and it loads that manufacturer 12 times - there are 12 cars in DatabaseOne by that Manufacturer where the featured image is set, and it is loading the same image and name 12 times, rather than load 1 car from that 1st Manufacturer, the second featured car from the 2nd Manufacturer, etc. Changing t3.ImageLink to t1.ImageLink then makes all 12 pictures load from that manufacturer.

Comment: I spent about 45 minutes working on this solution, and it is correct for the data you provided.

Comment: I will keep tweaking the code to try and fix it, feel free to comment back if you think you may have the solution in the meantime. This layered JOINing is new to me, so I'm not sure I can do much, but I will try.

Comment: I truly appreciate your time and response, I will try and figure out what is wrong on my end.

Comment: If you want a different answer, then you will have to change your original question.  But this might invalidate any work which others have already done.

Comment: Create a SQL Fiddle with whatever a representative sample of your actual data is.  Use my query, and then paste the link here.  I will have a look.  There may be a very quick fix to give you your desired output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105339/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-chris).

Comment: This is the correct answer, with a minor change on line 9 from INNER JOIN to RIGHT JOIN in my case. Thanks Tim!